# Use JS module in HTML and report <function> is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to import a function from a js file. But I got error "ReferenceError: greet is no defined."

Here is my code:

In module.js:

```html
export function greet(name) {
  console.log("Hello, " + name + "!");
}
```

In index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Accessing Module Functions in HTML</title>
  <script src="./module.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="greet('John')">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I can use `window.greet = greet;`  to solve this problem. But is anyway to solve this problem and avoid making this function global?

Comment: You have to explicitly import the `greet()` function into another script. Even then, you won't be able to access it from an "onclick" attribute. You can use `.addEventListener()` to set up a handler.

Answer (score 1):

By using JavaScript modules, your files have module scope, which means you could only make its content available for the outside world with the "export" keyword, and use them in another JS modules by the "import" keyword.

One solution could be:

- Give an "id" to your Button element
- Refer that "id" in your JS module
- Attach the click handler from the JS module
- Use HTML data attributes to make the "name" available in your module

Note that the "script" tag comes just right before the closing tag of the body element. This is because otherwise the JS module would try to find a button element, which is not yet there.

```js
document.getElementById("MyButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("Hello, " + this.dataset.name + "!");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Accessing Module Functions in HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="MyButton" data-name="John">Click Me</button>
  <script src="./module.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```